# Icons in the Android toolbox not showing clearly

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I setup Xamarin.Android on my visual studio 2015 today and things are looking good. The only thing I observed is that the controls icons in the Toolbox do not show up properly. Have you experienced anything like that below? How can I fix this?[image]

I then looked more and found all these messages

```
        Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidSdkDirectory not found.
        [I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidNdkDirectory found:
            Path contains ndk-stack in \. (C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK\android-ndk-r11c\).
        [I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\JavaSdkDirectory not found.
        [I:sdk]:                  Looking for Android SDK..
        [I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidSdkDirectory not found.
        [I:sdk]:                    Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidSdkDirectory found:
            Path does not contain adb in \platform-tools (C:\android-sdk-windows).
        [I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Xamarin\MonoAndroid\PrivateAndroidSdkPath not found.
        [I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Android SDK Tools\Path not found.
        [I:sdk]:                    Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Android SDK Tools\Path found:
            Path contains adb in \platform-tools (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk).
        [I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\JavaSdkDirectory not found.
        [I:sdk]:                    Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\JavaSdkDirectory not found.
        [I:sdk]:                  Looking for Java 6 SDK..
        [I:sdk]:                    Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\CurrentVersion found.
        [I:sdk]:                    Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\1.6\JavaHome not found.
        [I:sdk]:                    Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\1.7\JavaHome found:
            Path contains jarsigner.exe in \bin (C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55).
        [I:Unknown]:              Found Xamarin.Android 7.0.2
        [I:Unknown]:              Found Android SDK. API levels: 19, 21, 23
        [I:]:                     Tracking android devices started
        [D:]:                     Tracking avd started
        [D:]:                     avd watcher *.ini path: 'C:\Users\Oye\.android\avd'
        [D:]:                     TrackDeviceTask got: 
        [D:]:                     avd watcher android path: 'C:\PROGRA~2\Android\ANDROI~1\tools\android.BAT'
        [I:]:                     Got new device list from adb with 0 devices
        [D:]:                     avd watcher: got device list from avd with 1 devices
```

Comment: have you tried light theme?

Comment: I am completely new to Android development. What do I need to do to try that please?

Comment: its not about Android but about VisualStudio, you can try switching theme from dark to light of your IDE, maybe icons were designed for light theme only

Comment: Thanks. I just tried changing to light and still does not work.

Comment: I restarted my laptop and all those error messages went away but the Icons can still not be viewed properly.

Comment: Any help with this will be appreciated.